# Configure mocha-teamcity-reporter with Web Component Tester

Tags: unit-testing, polymer, teamcity, mocha.js, web-component-tester

I want my Web Component Tester (WCT) tests to be reported to TeamCity-CI. As WCT uses mocha as testing framework, I figure it makes sense to use the [mocha-teamcity-reporter](https://github.com/travisjeffery/mocha-teamcity-reporter).

The problem is; how can I configure Mocha/WCT with an extra reporter?

Comment: Worth checking out https://libraries.io/npm/wct-teamcity-reporter :)